# Can anyone explain the output for this code which is based on the concept of IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)

Tags: javascript, iife

```
(function(value){

    var names = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July",
                  "August","September","October","November","December"];

    value.name = function(number){
            return names[number];
    };

    value.number = function(name){
            return names.indexOf(name);
    };
})(this.month = {});

console.log(month.name(2));
console.log(month.number("November"));
```

Please help me explaining how this program works. I didn't understand why a new object is created outside the function and why ***this*** operators used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` will be the global object (since it isn't being used inside a function).

`this.month = {}` assigns a new object to `month` on the global object.

Assignments evaluate as the value assigned, so that gets passed to the function.

This is, essentially, just an ugly and unintuitive way to write:

```
function myFunction(value) {

    var names = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
        "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ];

    value.name = function(number) {
        return names[number];
    };

    value.number = function(name) {
        return names.indexOf(name);
    };
}

var month = {};
myFunction(month);
console.log(month.name(2));
console.log(month.number("November"));
```

It uses `this` because you can't use `var` inside a the `()` used to call a function.